# Server is not connecting

Tags: java, sockets, server, serversocket

I have a `void` method called `startServerConnection()` that connects the server to a port, in this case 7777. This method is called inside an action listener for a button in another class, `ClientGUI`.

I'm pretty sure the code is correct, but for some reason the only output I get is `"Waiting for connection..."`

```
    public void startServerConnection(){
        try{
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);

            while(true){
                System.out.println("Waiting for a connection...");
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connection established on port: "+clientSocket.getLocalPort());
                ClientConnection clientConnection = new ClientConnection(clientSocket);
                Thread thread = new Thread(clientConnection);
                thread.start();
            }   
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
Client class, connectClient method:

```
    public void connectClient(String user){
        try{
            host = clientSocket.getInetAddress();
            clientSocket = new Socket(host,port);
            new ClientHandler(clientSocket).run();
            String accepted = "Connection for host "+host+" accepted on port: "+clientSocket.getPort();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //sendMessage("Connection error: "+e);
            //serverGUI.appendEventsLog("Client "+new ClientGUI(username, port)+" failed to connect");
        }

    }
```

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: Servers don't connect. Clients connect; servers accept. If your server is never getting out of `accept()`, the client must be getting an exception. What is it? NB you won't find out by commenting-out the only code that can tell you. And don't vandalize your own posts.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

```
public void connectClient(String user){
    try{
        clientSocket = new Socket(host,port);
        // Use PrintWriter to send data out to server
        // Use BufferedReader to receive data from server
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //sendMessage("Connection error: "+e);
        //serverGUI.appendEventsLog("Client "+new ClientGUI(username, port)+" failed to connect");
    }
}
```

host is the IP address or the hostname, if server/client are running on the same machine, you can either use "127.0.0.1" or "localhost";  port is a value of `int`, in your case is 7777

Original:

`accept()` is a blocking function. the code afterwards would not go thorough until a connection is established.

You have to build a client side and request for connection, once the server and client is connected, you will see "Connection established on port.."

> public Socket accept() throws IOException
>
> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The method blocks until a connection is made.

Comment: yep, I'm also reading the link you just sent me. The writing of messages I'll do it in another class that handles an instance of each client. I'm struggling a bit to understand the `host`. Is that supposed to be a username or the IP address?

Comment: I thought host was the IP address, hence the host.getInetAddress() and pass it into the socket.

Comment: okay one last thing, so you suggest I invoke clientsocket like so: `Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 7777);` ?